# XCode 4 can't run executable on device

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

I upgraded to XCode4 today (installed it via standard installer) and since then, any attempt to run the application on my device is failing.

```
Project's Base SDK: 4.3
Target: iOS 4.2
```

My project was initially an XCode 3.2.x version and I was previously using it with XCode 4 Preview. Everything worked fine until I upgraded.

The debugger starts up the app but soon after, the app crashes and the following is reported in the debug window:

```
gdb stack crawl at point of internal error:
0   gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x000000010010974a internal_vproblem + 308
...
14  gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x0000000100072b49 catch_errors + 70


/SourceCache/gdb/gdb-1518/src/gdb/macosx/macosx-nat-dyld.c:1648: internal-error: unrecognized shared library breakpoint
A problem internal to GDB has been detected,
further debugging may prove unreliable.
```

This is pretty much the same thing that's being asked in this question but there was no answer:
[XCode 4 - Can run app in simulator but not in the device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256973/xcode-4-can-run-app-in-simulator-but-not-in-the-device)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wound up removing all of xcode and reinstalling it.

Answer (score 1):

I got same problem, I solved it by deleting xcuserdata/ and all of the files which contain with your userid in xxxx.xcodeproj/.